# Move folder to another computer including its windows 7 backup

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-7-backup

I have an old Windows 7 desktop that serves as a file server to a couple of users. The files are mainly documents. We use offline files so users can access the documents on the road. One bonus of using this setup is we can see the previous versions of each files.

Unfortunately, I have to decommission this desktop and move the folders to another desktop (more power efficient). Is there a way to move the folder to another computer and yet still have the previous versions available to the users, and at the same time, won't mess up the offline files?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [software similar to this](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/dc-professional/) to migrate the current OS to the new hardware, then enter the new W7 key and re-activate Windows. This assumes you are planning to use the same OS on the new hardware.

Comment: I would consider this as last resort. I think you can also do this without third party software: [link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135077-windows-7-installation-transfer-new-computer.html)